# Return new object by passing a callback function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I need to implement a function in which given a array of multiple objects:

```
var list = [
  {id: "102", name: "Alice"},
  {id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
  {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}];
```

must return whatever the object property callback function asks for:

```
{
  "3": [{id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."}],
  "5": [{id: "102", name: "Alice"},
        {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}]
 }
```

`groupBy(list, function(i) { return i.name.length; });`

For example: This callback is asking to return the name.length of each object plus the original object as its values and if they are the same, return it in the same array.

```js
var list = [
  {id: "102", name: "Alice"},
  {id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."},
  {id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}];

function groupBy(arr, cb) {
  var newObj = {};
  var newArr = [];
  
  for (key of arr) {
    newObj = cb(key);
  }
  return newObj;
}

groupBy(list, function(i) { return i.id; });
```

I don't have much going for my own solution and I've hit a wall. I would really appreciate it if you guys/gals would help me out.

Cheers

Comment: Is this a school class or a tutorial? This code occured quite often in the last time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an empty array for each new key, you like to group.

The push the actual object to this array.

```js
function groupBy(array, cb) {
    var result = {},
        key;
  
    for (object of array) {
        key = cb(object);
        result[key] = result[key] || [];
        result[key].push(object);
    }
    return result;
}

var list = [{ id: "102", name: "Alice" }, { id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr." }, { id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32 }];

console.log(groupBy(list, function(o) { return o.name.length; }));
console.log(groupBy(list, function(o) { return o.id; }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```